# How to change file/directory permission in BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry

Is is possible to set the permission of an existing directory/files in the SD card as read-only, which means it cannot be deleted by the user?

[FileConnection](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/microedition/io/file/FileConnection.html) has setWritable(). I tried using it, but still no luck.

```
FileConnection fconn = null;

try {
fconn = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/documents/TestDirectory/", Connector.READ_WRITE);

if (!fconn.exists()) fconn.mkdir();

// copyFile is taken from http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/copy-file/td-p/265877
copyFile("file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/documents/test.pdf","file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/documents/TestDirectory/test.pdf");
copyFile("file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/documents/data1.txt","file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/documents/TestDirectory/data1.txt");
copyFile("file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/music/gaudeamus.mp3","file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/documents/TestDirectory/gaudeamus.mp3");
fconn = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/documents/TestDirectory/", Connector.READ);              
fconn.setWriteable(false);
fconn.close();
}
catch (Exception e){

}
finally {
try {
    if (fconn != null) {
        fconn.close();
        fconn = null;
    }
} 
catch (Exception e) {
}
}
```

Comment: Could you share why do you need it?

Comment: A mobile network operator would like to bundle SIM card with SD card (with encrypted songs in it). A mobile app is provided for playing these songs.
Here's the logic of the app that is proposed, and we're asked whether this scenario is possible or not:
1. Before playing the song, mobile app sends APDU command to SIM card
2. The command is processed by SIM card, and returned to mobile app
3. If the response is SW 9000, then the mobile app will decrypt the song on the fly and play it.

Because the SD card is a part of the product, we don't want the users toe be able to read/modify the content :)

Comment: In theory, write protection on SD card is possible (if I understand it right). You can read it in the spec (https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/pls/simplified_specs/Part_1_Physical_Layer_Simplified_Specification_Ver_3.01_Final_100518.pdf). Search for SET_WRITE_PROT. But I guess the BB API doesn't support this.

Comment: If operator provides these sim cards I think there is way to make folder read only. But user still could format sd card. Also it's not fare to user limit his property. I would allow to delete and have download functionality and sure warn user if it costs additional money